# how can I skip install on one package in a monorepo managed by `nx`?

Tags: node.js, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I am using `nx` to manage a monorepo. There is one package which has a special dependency in its `package.json` file. This dependency requires some os level libraries pre-installed when running `yarn install`. That means `yarn install` on the root level will fail if missing this dependency.

Since different team is working on different projects, I don't want all teams setup those os level libraries just because one team has this depenency. Is there a way to configure `nx` to skip some packages during installation?

I know I can put this package in `.nxignore` but it will ignore all commands from nx. I only want to ignore `yarn install` but wants to include it when run `nx build ...`.